# netcdf files merging in python

Tags: python, h5py

I am trying to run a python script for aggregation of HDF5 data files. But it shows an error. Can somebody can figure it out? I am new to python.  Any help would be really appreciated. The program given below

```
import sys
import h5py
import numpy

Files = sys.argv[1:]  # get filename from command line

FirstFid = h5py.File(Files[0],'r') # Open first HDF5 file

FileInfo = {}
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\nasa\nasa_god.py", line 11, in <module>
    FirstFid = h5py.File(Files[0],'r') # Open first HDF5 file
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: what command do you run from your terminal??

Comment: This script works for me. How are you running it? `python nasa_god.py filename.h5`?